# Equality of container object identity instead of element-wise

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>                                                                                                   
 #include <vector>                                                                                                     
 using namespace std;                                                                                                  

 int main() {                                                                                                          
     vector<int> fst, snd;                                                                                             
     vector<int> trd = fst;                                                                                            
     cout << boolalpha << (fst == snd) << endl;                                                                                     
 }
```

The *operator==* is overloaded for vectors *fst, snd* to check element-wise equality.

Instead, how to check that *fst* references to the same object as *trd*? (In this case the keyword *is* used in *Python*.)

**@EDIT**

As all the answers and comments said, *object*, *object pointer* and *object reference* are distinguished concepts in *C++*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    // object pointer, heap allocated
    shared_ptr<vector<int>> fst(new vector<int>);
    auto snd = fst;

    fst->push_back(10);
    cout << boolalpha << (fst->size() == snd->size()) << endl;
    snd->push_back(20);
    cout << (fst->size() == snd->size()) << endl;
    fst = make_shared<vector<int>>();
    cout << (fst == snd) << endl;

    // object reference, aka alias
    vector<int> trd{3};
    auto &foth = trd;

    trd[0] = 30;
    cout << (trd[0] == foth[0]) << endl;
    foth[0] = 40;
    cout << (trd[0] == foth[0]) << endl;
    trd = {};
    cout << (trd == foth) << endl;

    // object copy, stack allocated
    vector<int> fith{5};
    auto sith = fith;

    fith[0] = 50;
    cout << (fith[0] == sith[0]) << endl;
    sith[0] = 60;
    cout << (fith[0] == sith[0]) << endl;
    fith = {};
    cout << (fith == sith) << endl;
}
```

Comment: They can't reference the same object. They are not pointers nor references.

Comment: For references you can compare addresses: `&fst == &trd`. But `fst` and `trd` in your question are not references, but distinct objects.

Comment: You have three distinct objects – the values of your variables are the actual objects, not references to them. References in the Python sense do not exist in C++.

Comment: In the general case, you can compare the addresses of two references to see if they reference the same object. The standard guarantees that pointers referring to different objects won't compare equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using C++, not Python. In C++, a variable of object type *is the object*; it doesn't "reference" anything. `fst` and `snd` are separate variables and therefore are separate objects. The only valid comparison is to ask the value of their objects if they are equivalent.

Variables of reference type don't provide the operation you're looking for either. A reference variable is intended to act (as much as practical) exactly like the object it references. References are commonly said to be a different name for the same object. So asking the question if two reference variables reference the same object is considered irrelevant in C++.

If you need to make this distinction between "referencing the same object" and "objects with the same value" (and you rarely do), then you need to use the C++ mechanism that provides that distinction: pointers. There, you can check for pointer equivalence (and thus "references the same object") or dereference the pointers and check for object equivalence.

Comment: But i would strongly suggest against storing pointers unless you have a very good reason to. And this is not one of them.

Comment: And if OP needs to, he can check if references refer to a same object, with `&a == &b`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to experiment around the question, here is an example
that tries to mimic the behavior of Python.
The values are only accessible through references (smart-pointers
here) so you have to explicitly say if you want to compare the
references (addresses) or the values.

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

using vec_t = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>;

int
main()
{
  const vec_t v1={std::make_shared<int>(1),
                  std::make_shared<int>(2),
                  std::make_shared<int>(3)};
  const vec_t v2={std::make_shared<int>(1),  // the three same values
                  std::make_shared<int>(2),  // but it's just a
                  std::make_shared<int>(3)}; // coincidence... 
  const vec_t v3=v1; // references to the same 3 data are shared between both vectors
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "compare references (addresses):\n";
  std::cout << "v1==v2 --> " << (v1==v2) << '\n'; // false
  std::cout << "v1==v3 --> " << (v1==v3) << '\n'; // true
  const auto same_values=
    [&](const auto &lhs, const auto &rhs)
    {
      return std::equal(cbegin(lhs), cend(lhs), cbegin(rhs), cend(rhs),
        [&](const auto &l, const auto &r)
        {
          return *l==*r; // dereference before comparing the values
        });
    };
  std::cout << "compare values:\n";
  std::cout << "same_values(v1, v2) --> " << same_values(v1, v2) << '\n'; // true
  std::cout << "same_values(v1, v3) --> " << same_values(v1, v3) << '\n'; // true
  return 0;
}
```